# XML Database or PostgreSQL

Tags: xml, postgresql

I need a database store/query XML.

My fundamental requirement is:

- Handles multiple xml data files, from multiple sources. XMLs are different from vendor to vendor.

Is it possible to store/query differents formats of XML on PostgreSQL?

or is it better to use a native XML solution, like Senda, XBase?

Thanks!

Comment: PostgreSQL can store any valid XML inside an `xml` column. But if you need to do heavy XQueries on that, I think an XML DB would probably be better suited.

Comment: If you want to do more than just store (valid) XML in PostgreSQL and some basic operations on it, you may be interested in [pg_xnode](http://www.pg-xnode.org/index.html). Be advised that it is still beta and I have not tested it myself.

Comment: It's hard to say from the detail provided. It depends a lot on the queries you want to run. For basic stuff PostgreSQL can happily use expression indexes on xpath expressions. For complex multi-format XML storage, a dedicated XML DB may well be the better choice, especially if you aren't already using Pg for other things.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL can meet your requirements and you can actually build very complex and sophisticated solutions around it.  The fundamental question is what else you are doing.  If it is just XML you may want to go with just an XML db.  If you are storing other information as well in association with the documents, PostgreSQL will be the better approach.

In short, are you just storing XML?  Maybe a document db would be best of some sort? Or do you need a hybrid relational/document db?  If the latter, PostgreSQL is a really good choice.